# How should I store my data if it has to be accessed from different contexts?

Tags: android, android-context

I query a bunch of data in the main activity of my application, via a `ContentProvider`, what I store in an `ArrayList`. I have to pass *certain* objects to other activities or services, based on user input, so regathering all the data what I need in the new context is really circumstantial and heavy work. I don't want to do that. How should I store and forward these objects between the app components?

Comment: Assuming your data is small (as your ArrayList choice makes it seem) i'd rather make it parcelable and throw it around in Intents and Broadcasts.

Answer (score 0):

if the data is small , go with the intent mechanism ... if you have a large set of data that is only needed for one session in the app , go with a singelton ...
If you need the data to be persistent , go with sqlite database ... you can also check some kind of ORM to avoid writing sql code ...

Answer (score 0):

You can create static class to store data

e.g.

```
public class temp_data {
   public static ArrayList arraylist;
   public static String str="temp string is it";
}
```

call in Mainactivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{ 

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+temp_data.str,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();         
}
```

it will toast "temp string is it"

note:-
- this data can store until the app not close if app close then data can lost.

- and data can access in of app activity,service or reciver just call

classname.variablename

Comment: Just be aware that this method may cause Nullpointer exceptions when device memory gets low, as the Garbage Collector may delete your static class and the data within it, as it may not realise the data is still needed.

Comment: then you can use database or shared preferences orther can not work,my suggestion to use database. it can easily store data like mysql or sql and easily to get data using query. try out https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html